# Using Firefox's 'View Source' with BBEdit results in a blank file

Tags: macos, firefox, text-editing

I use Firefox for browsing and BBEdit for text editing. I want the 'View Source' command in Firefox to display the source code in BBEdit rather than in Firefox's own window.

I have adjusted the Firefox config settings appropriately, by setting `view_source.editor.external` to `true` and `view_source.editor.path` to `/Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit.`

When I click on 'View Source' a new instance of BBEdit launches (even if one is already open), with a blank text document.

If I set the editor to TextEdit, it works fine, with the source code displayed in a TextEdit window. Why isn't it displaying in BBEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the command line tools for BBEdit. If you're not sure choose "Install Command Line Tools” from the BBEdit (application) menu.

Now in FireFox for the `view_source.editor.path` option enter `/usr/bin/bbedit` and it should work.